# How can I sort a vector containing pair<int,int> elements? Sorting is done as per the compare function

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stl

```
typedef pair<int,int>ii;
vector<ii>vii;

sort(vii.begin(),vii.end(),comp);

 ii comp(ii a,ii b){
   if(a.first>b.first)
   return a;
   else if(a.first==b.first){
    if(a.second>b.second)
    return a;
    else
    return b;
   }
   else{
    return b;
   }
 }
```

//This way it is throwing a compilation error. Can you guide how to sort this vector as per //the conditions given in the compare function.

Comment: You need to be more descriptive about the error you get and preferably include an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Typically, a compare function returns a boolean value indicating that a specific relation holds between the two passed values. They don't usually return one of the values passed in (what you have looks more like some approximation of a `max()` function than a comparator).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Presumably you want to sort them lexicographically, in increasing order. You can do this:

```
std::sort(vii.begin(), vii.end(), std::greater<std::pair<int,int>>());
```

The comparison functor is a binary predicate, and must return a boolean, and implement [*strict weak ordering*](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html). `std::greater<std::pair<int,int>>` does that for you.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the compare function you supply to `sort` must return `bool`, not the larger element.

Comment: @AlexReinking Correct, I was in the process of adding that.

Comment: it is throwing an error.  In function 'int main()':|
error: '>>' should be '> >' within a nested template argument list|

Comment: @AmitKumar You can replace `>>` by `> >`, or compile in C++11 mode. I was assuming a C++11 compiler.